# Facebook in-app notification not working

Tags: android, facebook

Here's my integration for in-app notifications

FCM Service

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "GrowFit";


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : remoteMessage.getData().entrySet()) {
        data.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    Intent defaultAction = new Intent(context, Dashboard.class)
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT)
            .putExtra("push", data);

    String title = data.getString("title");
    String body = data.getString("body");

    Vars.bundle = data;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Grow Fit", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        notificationChannel.setDescription("GrowFit Notifications");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.canShowBadge();
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_growfit)
            .setContentTitle(title == null ? "Hey" : title)
            .setContentText(body == null ? "Having a good day?" : body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    defaultAction,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            ));

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (mNotificationManager != null) {
        mNotificationManager.notify((int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE), mBuilder.build());
    }



NotificationsManager.presentNotification(this, data, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class), new NotificationsManager.NotificationExtender() {
                @Override
                public Notification.Builder extendNotification(@NonNull Notification.Builder builder) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
                    }
                    return mBuilder;
                }
            });
```

}

(**Single Top Activity** which handles the intent)

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    checkInAppPush(intent);
    checkFBPush();
}

private void checkInAppPush(Intent intent) {
    NotificationsManager.presentCardFromNotification(this, intent);
}
```

The intent has extras but in-app notificaiton is not rendered. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use android Notification Manager to present facebook In-app notification, to use fb In-app push noti >>you must have to integrate fb-notification library>> https://github.com/facebook/FBNotifications
after integrating fb notification ,you need to write NotificationManager.canPresentCard(data) in onMessageReceived method

```
 Bundle data = new Bundle();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : remoteMessage.getData().entrySet()) {
        data.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: "+ data.toString());

  if (NotificationsManager.canPresentCard(data)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: " + "PresentCard");
        NotificationsManager.presentNotification(
                this,
                data,
                new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)
                //MainActivity.getIntent(getApplicationContext(),data)
        );
   }
```

[here is my In-app noti](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msz8k.jpg)

Comment: then u can write above code in fcm onMessageReceieved

Comment: in your code you wrote android's notification and notification manager,if we want to present fb in-app noti we only need to write above code

Comment: The problem is Android Oreo, works on previous versions

Comment: Check my updated code where I try a fix for Oreo but it does not work